Problem sending images from react native to ASP.NET API
I get a 400 axios network error when making this request.
React Native Code
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Images', [
  { uri: selectedImage.uri, name: selectedImage.fileName, type: selectedImage.type },
] as any);

const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}`,
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
};
const res = await api.post(url, formData, {
  headers,
  transformResponse: () => formData,
  responseType: 'json',
  data: formData,
});
return res;

The type of property images is List in c#. I have been able to run the request succesfully using postman so the error must come from the way I am sending axios request. The error does not provide information about what goes on.
Thanks!

Please also share the code of your api method.
